# How to change the default permission when creating a file in ubuntu

Tags: permissions

In ubuntu, I use a program written by others. This program creates a file on my system and try to read and write it later. But the permission of the file it creates is read-only. How can I change the default permission when creating a file in ubuntu, in home folder. Thanks ahead.

Comment: It depends on the program you use. The program would create a file and set its permissions. So, unless you change the source code, you can't do much other than manually changing the permissions.

Comment: I tried to create a file by using vi. The owner is me. Files created by the program belong to root. Can I do something to change that?

Comment: Post the output of `umask`.

Comment: the output is 0002

Comment: And the output of `echo $USERNAME`? Also, what command do you use to create a file using `vi` ?

Comment: I got the answer. When I use sudo with other commands, the owner is root and when I use command without sudo, the owner is me. Thanks for ur help.

Comment: Post the answer and accept it. :) Also, `sudo` grants you superuser privileges, that is why if you need to edit some system files or run a program with root privileges, you have to use `sudo`. There is another command called `gksudo` which has the same effect except that it is used for graphical applications.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer with green7's help. When I use sudo with other commands, the owner is root and when I use command without sudo, the owner is me.